# Shogi without Japanese characters (kanji)

Tags: shogi

[On Wikipedia all the rules of Shogi are described](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi), but as a reference I find that the Japanese characters (kanji) get in the way and the explanation is otherwise very wordy and unconcise.  Is there an online resource that describes Shogi where kanji are not used or are only given as supplemental (instead of essential) information, or can someone give such a description as an answer?

Ideally the description would be as concise as possible and have diagrams where appropriate (board setup, piece movement).

Comment: Get used to the Kanji. It isn't that hard and it will allow you to read Japanese Shogi books, to a degree. Shogi is awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an [old chessbase article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170116214512/https://en.chessbase.com/post/garry-kasparov-taking-up-shogi-) that presents the shogi board with western chess style pieces.

It links to this [**introduction to shogi for chess players**](http://www.crockford.com/chess/shogi.html), which might be exactly what you are looking for.

But I would also second what Tony Ennis is commenting: You'll very quickly get used to the Kanji, it probably makes sense just to accept the slightly steeper learning curve the first two, three days.

Answer (score 3):

I think a turn-based multi boardgame site called brainking supplies information which is close to what you want. http://brainking.com/en/GameRules?tp=69

Answer (score 0):

The international piece sets are also supported on the lishogi and pychess sites, which are based of the lila code.

Other piece sets can be designed by using userstyles.

[image: lishogi example of international piece set]